# Chrome DevTools for React-Native cannot group source files by folder on Windows

Tags: react-native, google-chrome-devtools

When I debug `React-Native` the source files on the Page tab in `devtools` never groups the files by folder on Windows 10, it shows a list of all js files (including all files in node_modules).

I created a basic test app using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0"
},
```

Ran: `react-native run-android` started the debugger and see this:

[image]

But I'd like to see a folder structure like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

After some research, I discovered that the issue might be from the latest react update.

**1 - You can downgrade the version of your react project:**

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.52.2"
},
```

Then run these commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules android
npm install # this will bring folder node_modules back, with react/react-native of previous version
react-native eject # this will bring folder android back
react-native run-android
```

**Or**

**2 - Disable User JS Delta :**

Ctrl+m on your emulator, then click on Dev Settings.

Disable "User JS Delta" and restart the react native server. (Ctrl+c in the terminal and then `npm run android`).

Comment: What does the `User JS Delta` do?